# Why does the ping command take so long even though the response time <1MS

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

```
PS C:\Users\Family> Measure-Command { start-process ping -argumentlist 192.168.5.1 -wait}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 56
Ticks             : 40561631
TotalDays         : 4.69463321759259E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00112671197222222
TotalMinutes      : 0.0676027183333333
TotalSeconds      : 4.0561631
TotalMilliseconds : 4056.1631
```

The output of the the ping command

```
Pinging 192.168.5.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.5.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

As per the question, even though total round trip time should be `4 x 1ms + overhead of program execution` it takes way longer.

Is there a timeout before displaying each ping result, even if you have received a response? 
Is the delay in UI that significant? 
Or is there something else that makes the program this slow.

This is on win10 64bit. I'm sure there can be alternatives that provide a faster response time.

Comment: It’s kind of obvious when you run the command isn’t it? It delays 1 second after each ping and by default `ping` sends 4 pings. Use the `-n` and `-w` switches if you want different behavior.

Comment: yes why the delay? adding `-w 2` didn't change the timing much. as an aside how can i pass `-w 2` to the measure command

Comment: You can’t change the timing. It’s not Linux. `Ping` delays 1 second. If you want less delays then use `-n 1` to send only 1 ping and run the command multiple times as fast as you want. `-w` allows you to prevent ping from waiting for something like 2 seconds for a ping reply before failing.

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity you are right, changing to `-n 1` does resolve it instantly. I haven't been able to use `measure-command` with that parameter though. Anyway you should write an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Figured it out for `measure-command` , have to put the argumentlist in quotes. `Measure-Command { start-process ping -argumentlist "192.168.5.1 -n 1" -wait}`